# LINQ C# csv to xml resetting counter

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv

I'm trying to create a concise LINQ query to split a CSV file and convert to a XML file from a array of columns I have gleaned of a XSD file.

Its all working good. Except I just can't get the Counter to reset back to Zero after each row. It should go 0,1,2,3,4 then 0,1,2,3,4 but its going 0,1,2,3,4 then 5,6,7,8,9.

I'm new to LINQ so hopefully this is simple for someone with a bit of experience, thanks!

```
string[] columns = {"COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"};
int Counter = 0;

XElement cust = new XElement("Root",
 from str in source.Skip(1)
 let fields = str.Split(',') 
 select new XElement("Records",
 from c in columns
 select new XElement(c, fields[Counter++])
 )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is *not* the way to do this. It is extremely bad practice to have side-effecting functions (like an incrementor) inside a LINQ `select` clause, particularly because of things like parallelization. If you were doing this manually with a `foreach`, I *might* be tempted to just suggest use of a mod:

```
fields[(Counter++) % fields.Length]
```

But even that would still be a little weird.

This is a more acceptable way, which uses the [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method to find column names by matching them up by index.

```
string[] columns = {"COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"};

var rows = source.Skip(1)
                 .Select(c => columns.Zip(c.Split(','),
                                          (column, value) => new
                                                             {
                                                                 Column = column,
                                                                 Value = value
                                                             });

var elements = rows.Select(c => new XElement("Records",
                                             c.Select(x => new XElement(c.Column, c.Value))));

return new XElement("Root", elements);
```

That all said, it's important to note that this is not currently generalizable, and will fail when the columns contain quoted values with commas in them. You might want to look into third party libraries. I've had luck with [CsvHelper](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) myself.

Comment: Fair comment, I'm new to this but your suggestion is spot on.